# How to reshape an ndimensional array from shape (1600,105) to shape (1600,14,105) in python? Also how can I copy columns from one to the other?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I currently have an ndim array of shape `(1600,105)`, filled with data. I want to keep the existing data the same, but merely add a new axis of zeros in the middle, resulting in a ndarray of shape `(1600,14,105)`, where the original values remain the same. How do I do this in python / using numpy? Additionally I made an array of zeros of shape `(1600,14,105)`, but don't know how to copy the values from the original array to this one.

I tried adding a new axis, but am not sure how to reshape my current array from `(1600,105)` to `(1600,14,105)`. I tried making an np array of zeros of shape `(1600,14,105)`, using `array2 = np.zeros((1600,14,105))`. Now I want to copy the values from my original array1, which has shape `(1600, 105)`, into the corresponding axes in the new array.

```
array2 = np.zeros((1600,14,105))
array1.shape 
Out[1]:
  (1600, 105)
```

Comment: `array2[:,0,:] = array1` will copy `array1` to one `array2` - just one copy, leaving 13 like sized 'columns' zeros.  Or do you want 14 copies?  `array2[...] = array1[:,None,:]`?

Comment: I tried both of these and it's not exactly what I'm looking for. Imagine I have this (1600,105) array. I want to keep it exactly the same, but with a new dimension of size 14.

Comment: If you want to copy the data 14 times, `np.repeat(a[:, None, :], 14, axis=1)`. There may be a better way to do what you want if you're just trying to satisfy shape constraints for some vectorized operation.

Comment: An array with shape (1600,14,105) is 14 times larger. It either has to be mostly zeros or repeats.

Comment: Maybe you should add an example

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe what you are looking for is to add a dimension at the end instead of the middle. There are two ways you can do this:

Either the new dimension contains mostly zeros (or whatever value you want):

```
array2 = np.zeros((1600,105,14))
array2[:, :, 0] = array1
```

Or it contains repeats of the original array:

```
array2 = np.zeros((1600,105,14))
array2[:, :, :] = np.expand_dims(array1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [25]: arr = np.arange(1,13).reshape(3,4)                                                                  
In [26]: arr                                                                                                 
Out[26]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

A new array with added dimension of size 2:

```
In [28]: arr2 = np.zeros((3,2,4),int)                                                                        
In [29]: arr2                                                                                                
Out[29]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

One copy:

```
In [30]: arr2[:,0,:] = arr                                                                                   
In [31]: arr2                                                                                                
Out[31]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0]],

       [[ 5,  6,  7,  8],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11, 12],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0]]])
```

two copies:

```
In [32]: arr2[...] = arr[:,None,:]                                                                           
In [33]: arr2                                                                                                
Out[33]: 
array([[[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 1,  2,  3,  4]],

       [[ 5,  6,  7,  8],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11, 12],
        [ 9, 10, 11, 12]]])
```